# Cloning a drive with DriveImage XML renders the clone unbootable

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, external-hard-drive, clone, driveimagexml

I have a computer that I would like to completely transfer to new (better) hardware. I have an external hard drive, and I am attempting to clone the entire C: drive to it, making it bootable. The computer I"m trying to clone is 32 bit windows 7.

I downloaded DriveImage XML for this, which seems like a good tool to use for this purpose. I selected the "drive to drive" option, and chose for the C: drive to get cloned onto the external hard drive. It gives me an error along the lines of "Unable to lock DISK1 #1 (which is the number and partition of the external hard drive). I opted to ignore it, since there was little help on the web, and continued on with the rewrite.

The rest ran without a hitch, but hours later when it finished I plugged it into my 64 bit machine (windows 7 as well) and it wouldn't boot. I got your basic "Could not find bootable drive" or whatever. I'm wondering if I did something wrong, as most of the resources online give instructions to create a disk image and then extract it (which seems like it's an unnecessary step, and I'd need yet another hard drive as the middleman).

Should I try again (I'm reluctant to because it takes forever), try some other software, or do something completely different than what I'm doing?

Forgive me if this is obvious, I haven't done much messing with drives in the past.

UPDATE: I tried running a repair disc on the hard drive when trying to run it from the new machine. It looks like it did something though: Instead of no boot device recognized, the red and yellow windows 7 startup start to swirl around, and then it shuts down again. When I boot from it again it says that it failed the first time, and none of the safe mode etc. options work. Trying startup repair on the windows 7 repair disc makes it process for a while and eventually come up with a message that states it is unable to fix the issue. I am now going to reformat the external hard drive, download different disc cloning software, and try again. Any help in the meantime would be useful though!

Comment: You need to run the program again after you solve the problem of it not being able to lock the drive.

Comment: @ramhound What do you mean? I never was able to solve that problem, so I opted to ignore it. Ignoring caused it to continue on with the drive-to-drive copy, and restarting the copy made it send the error again.

Comment: I suspect the problem is because your trying to boot to a USB HDD instead of an internal.  I would try using the DriveImage media disk and restore the image outside of Windows.  There are other programs that might do a better job, there are also free tools like Clonezilla, but the lack of details makes it hard to actually answer this question.

Comment: @Ramhound I've looked for a little while, but I can't find a DriveImage media disk. I'm guessing it's a bootable DriveImage program? If that is the case, is it possible for me to load the program on a USB instead of a CD? I got this laptop secondhand and don't have access to the boot order. Can you link me to this? :)

Comment: You have to create the WinPE image yourself or use one that already [exists](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/backup-your-computer-with-driveimage-xml/)

Answer (score 2):

I know you've probably moved on to other things, but I wanted to add my two cents on the issue:

I'm simply trying to backup a system drive I pulled from another computer, on my computer. It's mounted externally, so it shouldn't be a problem, right?

I was under the impression that DriveImage XML could do an exact clone - this does not appear to be the case. In fact, DriveImage does not appear to "image" your drive, rather, it will copy *partitions*, and only those that are not hidden.

This introduces two problems if you want to move your system drive: First, the MBR is not going to be copied (thus the new drive will automatically not be bootable), and the special "System Reserved" partition Windows 7 typically installs will not be copied either.

RunTime mentions [this](https://www.runtime.org/driveimage_faq.htm#boot) on their FAQ page:

> Windows 7 provides all the challenges mentioned above. In addition, a Window 7 standard installation provides a boot manager that is located in a small partition preceding the Winows 7 partition. However, we found the Windows 7 installation DVD very helpful with fixing boot problems. If you do not get the drive to boot, put in the installation DVD and initiate a startup repair. Here is a comprehensive article on how to do that: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/ss/windows-7-startup-repair.htm

Thus, they themselves point out that DriveImage will not backup a drive bit-for-bit.

Now, since it looks like you've run the repair and got the boot files in order, you're experiencing a crashing issue - this isn't too surprising if you're trying to boot from different hardware. Most likely, Windows is trying to find a boot-critical device/driver that is not present on the new hardware.

As someone has suggested, creating a WinPE image could do the trick. As you're moving to new hardware though, it may not be a bad idea to just install Windows 7 fresh, and then copy over the files you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your software may not have set the boot flag on your boot partition. I would recommend using a partitioning tool to check this.

If all else fails, you can use a partitioning tool to copy your individual partitions across the drives. If you don't mind booting to a cd or flash drive, I would recommend using gparted (http://gparted.org/livecd.php). If you don't want to use a cd/flash drive, Windows software is available, such as Aomei (http://www.disk-partition.com).